# Facebook share url debugger warning

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

When I enter my url into [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I get this message:

```
Warnings That Should Be Fixed
1. Share App ID Missing        | The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

If I add my facebook page id like this:

```
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="{{ $app_id }}">
```

I get this error:

```
1. Extraneous Property        | Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:page_id'.
2. Share App ID Missing       | The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
3. Parser Mismatched Metadata | The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'fb:page_id'
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `fb:app_id` != `fb:page_id`

Comment: Ok, got it, but what about the app_id error ?

Comment: It’s not an error, it’s a warning. If you have an app that you want to associate with that URL (f.e. for the purpose of comment moderation) – then add it there, otherwise leave that meta tag out.